# Adicionando uma função com o prototype para criar cadeia de funções

Tags: javascript

Quero ver como funciona. Crio uma função assim:

```
function $( selector ){
    return document.querySelector( selector );
}
```

Como faço pra criar uma função `addClass()` para usar igual ao jQuery `$("#foo").addClass("bar")`, e futuramente criar uma cadeia de função tipo assim: `$("#foo").addClass("bar").setValue("value")`;

Deixo claro que não quero recriar o jQuery, é apenas a título de aprendizagem.